# Windows 8.1 Search selection highlighting not working properly

Tags: windows-8, keyboard-shortcuts, windows-search

I have a rather peculiar issue after doing a fresh win8.1 reinstall on my vaio sa3 notebook. Basically whats bothering me that if I use the windows search, i.e. <kbd>[image: Windows Key]</kbd>+<kbd>typing</kbd> or <kbd>[image: Windows Key]</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>, you expect the current selected item in the list to have a different background to highlight its selected. However this highlighting doesn't work at all anymore.

Any ideas what might cause this?

Regards,
Xaser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually found the solution by myself (not by googling just by checking everything that came to my mind).

Actually the solution was very simple and I already wanted to delete this question but then I thought, maybe there are other people like me that just can't figure it out, so here's my solution:

Start Page -> Charms Bar -> Settings -> Personalize: Select a different accent color than the background color, otherwise the "highlight selection" background will look exactly like the normal background and thus cannot be seen.

Regards,
Xaser